# Selenium jar file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried installing selenium with Java language but after extracting the file I couldn’t find the client combined.jar file to add it in eclipse.
Did they change its name or what cause it as I can’t find it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use with `Maven/ Gradle` and then add dependencies for `selenium`?